# JavaScript...Cannot call method match of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined` in my JavaScript. I'm trying to write this without jQuery since it'll be the only js on the site.

My code is supposed to add a class, "active", to the `<a href="...>` in the navigation that links to the current page.

I'm guessing it might be the `contentLoaded` function?....[source](https://github.com/dperini/ContentLoaded/blob/master/src/contentloaded.js)

Here's my code...(error occurs on line 9)...[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHZEf/)

```
(function(window, document, undefined) { contentLoaded(window, function() {

  var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0],
      nav_anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0]
                            .getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
                            .getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(i in nav_anchors)
    if(nav_anchors[i].href.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0] = page) //LINE 9 <-- Error
      nav_anchors[i].classList.add('active');

})
})(this, this.document)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `for (x in y)` to browse an array or a NodeList. Use a regular `for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i)` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NodeLists` have `length`, `item` and `namedItem` properties.

Use `for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)` not `for i in foo` to iterate over them and only hit the nodes.

Comment: and the best way is `for (var i = 0, j = foo.length; i < j; ++i)`

Comment: That's entering the land of less readable micro optimisations. No point in doing it unless there is a performance problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(window, document, undefined) { contentLoaded(window, function() {

  var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0],
      nav_anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0]
                            .getElementsByTagName('nav')[0]
                            .getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(var i=0;i<nav_anchors.length;i++)
    if(typeof nav_anchors[i].href != "undefined" && nav_anchors[i].href.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0] == page)
      nav_anchors[i].classList.add('active');

})
})(this, this.document)
```

Added a check if the `href` of the anchor is set, in case you have page anchors without href attributes (Such as `<a name="top">` called using #top). Added a second `=` in the `IF` for it to work as exepected. And corrected the for syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(nav_anchors[i].href.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0] = page) //LINE 9 <-- Error
```

In javaScript the equals sign `=` is an assignment operator. You probably mean double equals `==` where you can check values without type coercion (`5 == "5"`) or triple equals `===` for strong typed checks (where `5 !== "5"`).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `document.location.pathname.match(/[A-z]+$/)` can be null. If you try to use `document.location.pathname.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0]` you can not access the 0 Element of null.

Comment: Maybe this is better? `document.location.toString().match(/[A-z\-\_]+$/)[0]`

Comment: use somne code like this maybe: `var page = document.location.pathname.match(/[A-z]+$/); if(typeof page === "object") page = page[0];`